# Adding column with foreign key and reference

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying following query:

```
ALTER TABLE `booking` 
ADD  `feedback_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED,
INDEX `b_feedback_fk_idx` (`feedback_id` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `feedback_fk`
    FOREIGN KEY (`feedback_id`)
    REFERENCES feedback(`id`)
```

but it is giving following error:

```
Query: ALTER TABLE `booking` ADD `feedback_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED, INDEX `b_feedback_fk_idx` (`feedback_id` ASC), CONSTRAINT `feedback_fk...

Error Code: 1064
Erreur de syntaxe près de '`b_feedback_fk_idx` (`feedback_id` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `feedback_fk`
    FOREIGN ' à la ligne 4
```

Comment: first add column, next add index and constraint and give information about result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to add new index and foreign key constraint, you need to use `ADD` before `INDEX` and `CONSTRAINT`.

```
ALTER TABLE `booking` 
ADD  `feedback_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED,
ADD INDEX `b_feedback_fk_idx` (`feedback_id` ASC),
ADD CONSTRAINT `feedback_fk` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`feedback_id`)
    REFERENCES feedback(`id`)
```

See [MySQL ALTER TABLE syntax documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html).